# Найти обратный элемент в конечном поле

Tags: криптография, теория-чисел

Интересует такой вопрос. У нас есть поле Галуа GF(2^8), в нем задается элемент в байтовом представлении (допустим, А = 1Е, то бишь 00011110 в двоичной системе счисления, а значит, если представлять элемент в виде полинома, А = х^4 + х^3 + х^2 + х).

Необходимо найти элемент данного поля, обратный этому, то есть А^(-1).

Знаю, что это нужно(можно) реализовывать с помощью расширенного алгоритма Евклида, но не совсем понимаю, как сделать это «на бумаге». Желательно более подробное описание представить.
Спасибо!

Comment: при таком кол-ве элементов можно просто перебрать все элементы.

Comment: @KoVadim можете, пожалуйста, уточнить, каким образом?

Comment: у Вас всего то 256 элементов. Можно ручками просчитать. Да, накладненько, но ..  похоже 2 является ответом - 2^4 + 2^3 + 2 ^ 2 + 2 = 16+8+4+2 = 30 = 1Eh

Comment: @KoVadim ох, так вот как сделать можно… действительно. спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `GF(256)` - это, на самом деле, множество изоморфных полей - полей характеристики 2 по неприводимому полиному степени 7. Тыкая пальцем в небо, предположу, что таких полей 128 штук. Для того, чтобы вычислить обратный элемент в конкретном поле, нужен конкретный многочлен

Comment: @PakUula под "конкретным многочленом" вы подразумеваете неприводимый для данного поля? если в 16-ричной СС, то это '11B', то бишь x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1 в виде полинома